# What does "Searching Taps" Mean with HomeBrew?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, homebrew

I tried installing a c++ library by doing the following, and got the message below:

What does this mean? Did it install or did it not? I'm new to homebrew. Thanks!

```
macbook-2:~ ME$ brew install ceres-solver
Error: No available formula for ceres-solver 
Searching taps...
homebrew/science/ceres-solver
macbook-2:~ ME$
```

Comment: It means they over-extended their metaphor.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Homebrew Formula Cookbook](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md):

- **Formula** - The package definition - /usr/local/Library/Formula/foo.rb
- **Keg** - The installation prefix of a **Formula** - /usr/local/Cellar/foo/0.1
- **opt prefix** - A symlink to the active version of a **Keg** - /usr/local/opt/foo
- **Cellar** - All **Kegs** are installed here - /usr/local/Cellar
- **Tap** - An optional Git repository of **Formulae** and/or commands - /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions
- **Bottle** - Pre-built **Keg** used instead of building from source - qt-4.8.4.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz

I suggest starting with the Introduction on the same page.